# Apache Camel: Problem POSTing request body

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel

I have a server and client application that both use Apache Camel to configure and manage their routing. I am trying to use the REST component to make a POST request from the client to the server, and send a message in the request body. It seems that the REST endpoint is being invoked, but the body is not making it through. I assume I'm either missing some steps, or I'm doing it incorrectly.

Another thing to mention is that I'm using a generic message class that can essentially contain any object (including arrays of bytes or chars). Perhaps this is part (or maybe all) of the cause behind the problems I'm having.

GenericMessage.java:

```
public class GenericMessage<T extends Object> {
  private T payload;

  public GenericMessage(T payload) {
    this.payload = payload;
  }

  public T getPayload() {
    return payload;
  }

  public void setPayload(T payload) {
    this.payload = payload;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "GenericMessage [payload=" + payload + "]";
  }
}
```

Server

camel-context.xml:

```
  <camelContext id="camel-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <restConfiguration component="jetty" bindingMode="json"
      contextPath="/" host="localhost" port="9100">
      <dataFormatProperty key="prettyPrint" value="true" />
    </restConfiguration>

    <rest>
      <get uri="/data?size={size}" produces="JSON">
        <route id="get-data-by-size">
          <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="start - get-data-by-size" />
          <process ref="get-request-processor" />
          <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="end - get-data-by-size" />
        </route>
      </get>

      <post uri="post-data" consumes="json">
        <route id="post-data">
          <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="start - post-data" />
          <process ref="post-request-processor" />
          <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="end - post-data" />
        </route>
      </post>
    </rest>
  </camelContext>
```

GetRequestProcessor.java:

```
@Component("get-request-processor")
public class GetRequestProcessor implements Processor {
  @Autowired
  private DataProvider provider;

  public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    int size = exchange.getIn().getHeader("size", Integer.class);
    // TODO currently only sends char[] data
    GenericMessage<?> data = provider.getCharData(size);
    exchange.getMessage().setBody(data, GenericMessage.class);
  }
}
```

PostRequestProcessor.java:

```
@Component("post-request-processor")
public class PostRequestProcessor implements Processor {
  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PostRequestProcessor.class);

  public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    GenericMessage<?> data = exchange.getIn().getBody(GenericMessage.class);

    if (data != null) {
      logger.info("process: object received: {}", data);
    } else {
      logger.warn("process: null object");
    }
  }
}
```

DataProvider.java:

```
@Component
public class DataProvider {
  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataProvider.class);

  public GenericMessage<?> getByteData(final int size) {
    logger.info("getByteData: size={}", size);
    return new GenericMessage<byte[]>(DataGenerator.generateByteArray(size));
  }

  public GenericMessage<?> getCharData(final int size) {
    logger.info("getCharData: size={}", size);
    return new GenericMessage<char[]>(DataGenerator.generateCharArray(size));
  }
}
```

Client

camel-context.xml:

```
  <camelContext id="camel-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <restConfiguration component="jetty" bindingMode="json"
      contextPath="/" host="{{http-client.server.host}}"
      port="{{http-client.server.port}}">
      <dataFormatProperty key="prettyPrint" value="true" />
    </restConfiguration>

    <route id="rest-get">
      <from
        uri="timer:{{http-client.timers.http-get.name}}?delay={{http-client.timers.http-get.start-delay}}&amp;fixedRate=true&amp;period={{http-client.timers.http-get.period}}&amp;repeatCount={{http-client.timers.http-get.repeat-count}}" />
      <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="start - rest-get" />
      <to uri="rest:get:{{http-client.endpoints.http-get}}" />
      <process ref="process-get-response" />
      <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="end - rest-get" />
    </route>

    <route id="rest-post">
      <from
        uri="timer:{{http-client.timers.http-post.name}}?delay={{http-client.timers.http-post.start-delay}}&amp;fixedRate=true&amp;period={{http-client.timers.http-post.period}}&amp;repeatCount={{http-client.timers.http-post.repeat-count}}" />
      <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="start - rest-post" />
      <process ref="add-post-body" />
      <to uri="rest:post:{{http-client.endpoints.http-post}}" />
      <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="end - rest-post" />
    </route>
  </camelContext>
```

AddPostRequestBody.java:

```
@Component("add-post-body")
public class AddPostRequestBody implements Processor {
  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AddPostRequestBody.class);

  @Autowired
  private DataProvider provider;

  @Override
  public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    GenericMessage<?> data = null;
    int intValue = RandomUtil.generateInt(1);

    switch (intValue) {
      case 0:
        data = provider.produceByteArrayData();
        break;
      case 1:
        data = provider.produceCharArrayData();
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

    logger.info("adding POST request body:\n{}", data);

    exchange.getMessage().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, "POST");
    exchange.getMessage().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
    exchange.getMessage().setBody(data, GenericMessage.class);
  }
}
```

GetResponseProcessor.java:

```
@Component("process-get-response")
public class GetResponseProcessor implements Processor {
  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GetResponseProcessor.class);

  @Override
  public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    GenericMessage<?> body = (GenericMessage<?>) exchange.getIn().getBody();
    logger.info("body: {}", body);
  }
}
```

DataProvider.java:

```
@Component
public class DataProvider {
  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataProvider.class);

  public GenericMessage<byte[]> produceByteArrayData() {
    int size = RandomUtil.generateInt(1000, 20000000);
    byte[] bytes = DataGenerator.generateByteArray(size);
    logger.info("produceByteArrayData: generated {} bytes", size);
    GenericMessage<byte[]> data = new GenericMessage<>(bytes);
    return data;
  }

  public GenericMessage<char[]> produceCharArrayData() {
    int size = RandomUtil.generateInt(1000, 20000000);
    char[] chars = DataGenerator.generateCharArray(size);
    logger.info("produceCharArrayData: generated {} characters", size);
    GenericMessage<char[]> data = new GenericMessage<>(chars);
    return data;
  }
}
```

I have it configured to do one POST request from the client. There are logging statements scattered about to give an idea what is going on.

Client console:

```
2020-04-13 13:23:39.805  INFO 17464 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext           : Route: rest-get started and consuming from: timer://http-get
2020-04-13 13:23:39.806  INFO 17464 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext           : Route: rest-post started and consuming from: timer://http-post
2020-04-13 13:23:39.812  INFO 17464 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext           : Total 2 routes, of which 2 are started
2020-04-13 13:23:39.812  INFO 17464 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext           : Apache Camel 3.1.0 (CamelContext: RESTClient) started in 1.679 seconds
2020-04-13 13:23:42.308  INFO 17464 --- [mer://http-post] rest-post                                : start - rest-post
2020-04-13 13:23:42.312  INFO 17464 --- [mer://http-post] e.m.l.m.s.DataProvider                   : produceCharArrayData: generated 1039 characters
2020-04-13 13:23:42.313  INFO 17464 --- [mer://http-post] e.m.l.m.p.AddPostRequestBody             : CLIENT: Adding POST request body:
GenericMessage [payload=[C@2124c204]
2020-04-13 13:23:42.408  INFO 17464 --- [mer://http-post] rest-post                                : end - rest-post
```

Server console:

```
2020-04-13 13:23:10.846  INFO 23260 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext           : Route: get-data-by-size started and consuming from: jetty:http://localhost:9100/data
2020-04-13 13:23:10.847  INFO 23260 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext           : Route: post-data started and consuming from: jetty:http://localhost:9100/post-data
2020-04-13 13:23:10.852  INFO 23260 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext           : Total 2 routes, of which 2 are started
2020-04-13 13:23:10.853  INFO 23260 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext           : Apache Camel 3.1.0 (CamelContext: RESTServer) started in 0.314 seconds
2020-04-13 13:23:42.395  INFO 23260 --- [tp1276761134-37] post-data                                : start - post-data
2020-04-13 13:23:42.396  INFO 23260 --- [tp1276761134-37] e.m.l.m.p.PostRequestProcessor           : SERVER: Processing POST request
2020-04-13 13:23:42.400  WARN 23260 --- [tp1276761134-37] e.m.l.m.p.PostRequestProcessor           : null object
2020-04-13 13:23:42.400  INFO 23260 --- [tp1276761134-37] post-data                                : end - post-data
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the incoming data on the server, once it's received at the POST endpoint. It's not clear in `PostRequestProcessor` what you intend to do with the data. Does it need to be processed in a certain way, depending on the type of the message?

Comment: The server doesn't need to do anything with the received message/data, at least not for the time being. The problem is that I'm only seeing null in the processor. It looks like the exchange contains no body.

Comment: Does your GET call send the request body? I'm testing with Postman, and the request body is only sent with a POST request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Camel doesn't know your `GenericMessage` class, so it doesn't know how to convert to/from it.

Camel uses pluggable [type converters](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/type-converter.html) to tell it how to convert a message (Body) between different types of objects.

The built-in type converters cover a lot of common cases (e.g. String to Integer, Iterator to ArrayList, etc), but they don't know how to convert to or from any custom classes you write.

That is why this line in the Server Processor returns null:

```java
GenericMessage<?> data = exchange.getIn().getBody(GenericMessage.class);
```

Because at the time, the Body is a Stream, but Camel doesn't know how to convert it to the `GenericMessage` you've asked for.

(The default behaviour of [`getBody(Class<T>)`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.camel/camel-api/3.2.0/org/apache/camel/Message.html#getBody-java.lang.Class-) is to return *null* if it can't convert. Try using [`getMandatoryBody(Class<T>)`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.camel/camel-api/3.2.0/org/apache/camel/Message.html#getMandatoryBody-java.lang.Class-) if you want an Exception to be thrown instead.)

On the client side: how do you get the response as a `GenericMessage`? You need to use *unmarshalling*. You unmarshal the JSON first, into a Java object. It's at this point that you need to give Camel a hint of which class to unmarshal to.

```
<dataFormats>
    <json id="myGeneric" .... unmarshalTypeName="....GenericMessage"/>
</dataFormats>

...
<unmarshal><custom ref="myGeneric"/></unmarshal>
```

Then the Body will be your `GenericMessage` type.

Note that in Camel, type conversion and marshalling/unmarshalling are two different things.

**On the Server side:** Camel will try to unmarshal a request from JSON to a simple Java object (e.g. a HashMap, etc.) automatically. To tell it to unmarshal to a specific POJO, set a `type` on the REST verb definition, e.g.:

```xml
<post uri="post-data" consumes="json" type="com.example.demo.GenericMessage">
```

You can also use the same approach to define an `outType` (for marshalling the response back to JSON)

Comment: OK, so I tried the following: I added the `<dataFormats>` and `<unmarshal>` blocks in the server context. Now I get the following in the server console: 
`Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: java.util.LinkedHashMap to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value {payload=<collection of chars>}`

Comment: Sounds like on the Server side, Camel was already marshalling from JSON to a HashMap for you. I've updated my answer. Set `type`.